# Calling Fork for a subprocess

Tags: c, fork, execvp

I am implementing a shell in C but when Im using fork() it creates too child process.
Here is my code :

```
int exec_simple_command(struct ast_node_simple_command *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return 1;


    char **args = node->words;
    if (args == NULL)
        return 1;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    int status;

    /* Error handling */
    if (pid < 0)
        return -1;

    if (pid == 0) /* Child Process */
    {
        return exec_builtin(args);
    }
    else
    {
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
        {
            return 2;
        }

        return 0;

    }
}
```

i have file with simple command to test my shell :

```
echo 1;
echo 2;
echo 3;
echo 4;
```

And here is the output i get :

```
1
2
3
4
4
3
4
4
2
3
4
4
3
4
4
```

every time I execute a new builtin it duplicates the number of child.
I just want to execute on child, wait before the child process terminated and then continue the rest of the program.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: the child process should exit after it runs the command

Comment: I returrn the return value of exec_builtin so it exit the child process right ?

Comment: no? return just returns. return doesn't exit

Comment: @Nicolas  No.  The posted code will return to whatever called the `exec_simple_command()` function, with the same call stack.  But only the tread that called `fork()` will exist.

Comment: Normally, if the command is a built-in, you don't fork before running it.  The point of a built-in command is that it is _not_ executed in a separate process.  For commands like `cd`, that is important.

Comment: @user253751 i added exit(0) after the exec_builtin, it didn't change anything.

Comment: did you add exit(0) after return? because return returns and that means the next line in the function does not run.

Comment: The problem very much appears to be that `exec_builtin()` returns (at all).  It shouldn't.  But we can't tell whether it really does or why, because you have not presented that function.  Nor can we judge whether there may be an error in `exec_simple_command()`'s caller, because you have not presented that.  This sort of thing is why we generally expect debugging questions such as this one to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In *nix for instance, if we execute `> command &` I think it is supposed to run on background even if built-in? How would one achieve it without a separate process?

Comment: @EugeneSh., `command` may be a built-in command, but that does not make `command &` one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hm.. I just did `cd .. &`, and it did *something*, not sure what :) It did not change the current directory though.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  There's a `/bin/cd` on the RHEL 8 system I'm currently working on.  And FWIW, [`cd` is a POSIX-specified utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cd.html).  Although IMO a separate `cd` utility is, umm, of *questionable* utility.

Comment: The POSIX terminology would be "built-in *utility*" and "simple *command*".  `cd` is ordinarily a built-in utility, though it may also be available as an external one.  `cd .. &` is a simple command.  The `&` control operator requires that the (rest of) the command be executed in a subshell, which might or might not involve forking, but that's a separate consideration from whether excuting the `cd` utility itself involves forking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. — when there's a background process, there's a new process.  Within that child process, the built-in is executed in the child, without a grandchild process being created.  Hence your `cd .. &` creates a process because of the `&` and that child process does the `cd` and exits (without affecting the process that ran the `cd .. &` command).